# BLE connection to socket

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the service BLE to socket connection. When trying to connect, he receives the error:

> I/System.out: Status: connection failed: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void
> com.bart111.project.bluetooth.SerialService.connect(com.bart111.project.bluetooth.SerialSocket)'
> on a null object reference

Where do I go wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, ServiceConnection, SerialListener {

    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private MapsFragment mapsFragment;
    private TabBarView myTabbar;

    private enum Connected { False, Pending, True }
    private String deviceAddress;
    private SerialService service;

    private Connected connected = Connected.False;
    private boolean initialStart = true;
    private boolean hexEnabled = false;


    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        service = ((SerialService.SerialBinder) binder).getService();
        service.attach(this);
        if(initialStart) {
            initialStart = false;
            runOnUiThread((this::connect));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();

        // Read BLE device.
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("BLEPreferences", 0);
        String BLEDevice = (pref.getString("device", ""));
        if (BLEDevice.equals(""))
            startActivity(new Intent(this, BluetoothActivity.class));
        else
            deviceAddress = BLEDevice;
         

}

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(service != null) {
            service.attach(this);
        } else {
            bindService(new Intent(this, SerialService.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(new Intent(this, SerialService.class));
            connect();
        }

    }

 private void connect() {
        try {
            BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
            status("connecting...");
            connected = Connected.Pending;
            SerialSocket socket = new SerialSocket(getApplicationContext(), device);
            service.connect(socket);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            onSerialConnectError(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `serialService` but have not assigned a value to it, hence the null object reference. You should assign initialize the `serialService` object before trying to invoke it.

Comment: Ok, i added startService in onStart but not understand why func onServiceConnected not working. code edited.